# Android Architecture Components Room ViewModel CompleteableFormAction

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

So I thought I would try `Room` out on a small side-project.
I followed Florina Muntenescu’s example project:
[android-architecture-components](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components)

I am paying particular attention to classes: [UserActivity.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/ui/UserActivity.kt), [UserViewModel.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/ui/UserViewModel.kt), [UserDao.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/persistence/UserDao.kt)

`UserViewModel#updateUserName()` returns a [Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html) and has to be subscribed to returning `onComplete` or `onError`

When I attempt to put my equivalent of `viewModel.updateUserName(userName)` into an `RxBindings` chain.
If I subscribe to it *normally* I am passed a `Disposable!` into the `onNext` with a value of `"DISPOSED"` in the final `.subscribe`

The issue is that this will not emit an *Error* and thus never know if there is an issue

How could I adapt the code below so that the final `.subscribe` would return the *correct* events?

```
RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
            .debounce(250L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, schedulers.main)
            .subscribeOn(schedulers.main)
            .observeOn(schedulers.disk)
            .map({ name ->
                viewModel.updateUserName(name)
                        .subscribe(
                                { Timber.d(“Success”) },
                                { error -> Timber.d(error, “something went wrong”)) })                    
            })
            .observeOn(schedulers.main)
            .subscribe(
                    { Timber.d("name changed $it}") },
                    { Timber.e(it, "name error") })
```

Thanks in advance

M.

Answer (score 0):

Turn this

```
.map({ name ->
       viewModel.updateUserName(name)
                 .subscribe(
                  { Timber.d(“Success”) },
                 { error -> Timber.d(error, “something went wrong”)) })                    
            })
```

To this

```
.flatMapCompletable name ->
           viewModel.updateUserName(name))
```

Comment: I never knew of that operator, I started to write something like:
    `.flatMap({ name ->
                    var res = Observable.empty<String>()
                    vM. updateUserName(name)
                            .subscribe({
                                        res = Observable.just("success")
                                    },
                                    { error -> res = Observable.error<String>(error)
                                    })
                    result})`